# How to translate ListView texts?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

My android application includes `ListView` binded with `SimpleCursorAdapter` to the database. This database contains column, which contains data like

```
somenameofrow
anothername
thirdname
```

However instead of directly displaying these texts in the `ListView`, I would like to read according texts (actually - translations) from the Android resources.
How should I do it?

I think that I can use `setViewValue` for the same, `name` in the code below is `TextView` item, which displays my text:

```
case R.id.name:
    TextView elName = (TextView) view;
    elName.setText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.));
    return true;
```

I am not sure how to understand what is correct id of the resource I am looking for (probably, `cursor.getString(columnIndex)` or `elName.getText()`) and how to get the value?

**Upd.** What if I exclude names from the database and will use ids instead. Will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the android guide [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html), you will find:

> Note that using a hard-coded string array is not the best design practice. One is used in this tutorial for simplicity, in order to demonstrate the ListView widget. The better practice is to reference a string array defined by an external resource, such as with a  resource in your project res/values/strings.xml file

Simply create different `string-array`s items in res/values-XX, where XX are the locales you want to translate.

See the dev guide for more details about resources and i18n: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: @Aleadam, thanks! How should I link this `string-array` to the database entries?

Comment: @LA_ you have a working example in the tutorial I linked above.

Comment: Thanks, @Aleadam. However, I still don't understand how to use that approach with SimpleCursorAdapter and not with ArrayAdapter (what is given in the tutorial). Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @LA_ you retrive the resource as `String[] myStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);`. Then, you can use your (already translated to the right language) String array as you please.

Comment: @Aleadam, sorry - still don't understand. Currently I have the following code: 
`String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, 
    DbAdapter.KEY_TIME,
    DbAdapter.KEY_FAVORITE};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.time, R.id.icon};

items = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myCursor, from, to);`
where in this code I should use myStrings?

Comment: I.e. it is clear how it can be done in case when ListView displays only one db column, but not clear how to do the same with several columns, when one should be translated.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to read the text from a db or from res? Or perhaps you want to parse the string from the db and replace the words with a list from res? I'm quite lost about what you want.

Comment: OK, if you want one column translated, put that string array in each res/values-XX, while the rest of the "columns" would be string-arrays in the res/values folder (with no translations in res/values-xx)

Comment: @Aleadam, I have several records in the sqlite database. I need to display them in the ListView. But one field from the database (`name`) should be translated. Probably, this is wrong design - db content is flexible, when translation file is not - so, I should really keep translations in the database instead.

Comment: @LA_ in that case I suggest you to have `HashMap`s with the translations, and search for the word in the corresponding HashMap for that language. Resources are not well suited for changing content.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, since id's are generated in some basically sem-random way during compilation, so you can't be sure which id will have specific `String` resource.

I would suggest to use translation from DB or you can read translations from assets

Comment: What is about getIdentifier()? Can it be used? If I have translations in the database, how can I understand which lang I should use?

Comment: @LA Use Locale.getDefault() - to understand which language is default in this device right now. Concerning getIdentifier() - it's the same as R.string.id